# What equivalent code by MagickCore or ImageMagick like that?

Tags: c++, imagemagick

What equivalent code by MagickCore or ImageMagick with this Command?

```
cjpeg -progressive -dct float -qtables qtopt.Q.psnr.$PSNR.000 $FILE.srgb.pnm > $FILE-$PSNR.ipnet.jpg;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used -progressive and do not know about most of the options you are usng in your code but this should do part of what you want. You may need to change the position of -interlace in your final code. See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#interlace

```
convert input -interlace line output
```

There is plenty of information on quantum if you check the rest of the page linked above.